# HTTPS redirects in nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, https

I'm trying to redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS. The web server I'm using is nginx. This is the server block I'm using to do the redirect.

```
server {
    listen      80;
    rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

This successfully redirects URLs like `http://localhost` to `https://localhost`. However, for URLs like `http://localhost/table/` I get redirected to `https://table` which is incorrect. I would like it to re-direct to `https://localhost/table/`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Update:
It seems that the rewrite scheme has a problem with trailing slashes. For example, `http://localhost/table` gets correctly redirected but `http://localhost/table/` does not.

Comment: can you try to hardcode the server name like https:// localhost$request_uri? permanent; and check if it works

Comment: Hard coding the server name to localhost fixes it. However, other machines cannot access it as they get redirected to localhost, instead  of the server name.

Comment: Ok, so nginx is not getting $server_name. Set the servername $server_name domain.com

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. To test it out, I've set server_name  and I still get the same behaviour. It looks like the rewrite rule is getting confused and is treating /table/ as the server name.

Comment: Are you sure that your problem isn't in your https server configuration?

Answer (score 2):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    rewrite 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables